# Show content of another page For not found Urls

Tags: .htaccess

When Users Visits some not found url like `domain.com/blogs/blogs1/randomblabla.html` , I need them to show the contents of `domain.com/blogs/blogs1/index.php` .

I tried something like below and placed the code in `domain.com/blogs/blogs1/.htaccess` , but it shows content of homepage(domain.com/index.php) , but i need content of `domain.com/blogs/blogs1/index.php` to be shown

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule (.*)(\/?)$ / [QSA,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple 404 redirect in .htaccess should be sufficient?

```
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
```